# "I made sure we choose/chose items that doesn’t use the most plastic."

Tags: tense, past-simple, backshifting

In the following sentence:

> Yesterday, when I was shopping with my mum, I made sure we **choose** items that doesn’t use the most plastic.

Which is correct: to say I made sure we (choose) or (chose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chose - but neither work in that context. You could use "chose" if you said:

> I made sure we chose items that *didn't* use the most plastic.

It is incorrect to use choose in either scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Kindly, could you help me with this short paragraph from which I quoted the sentence. I just need to know, is there any other grammatical mistakes in this text:


Yesterday, when I was shopping with my mum, I made sure we chose items that didn’t use the most plastic. It’s better to package things in paper or glass. Today, I am going to my friend’s house and we are going to swap our old computer games. This is better for the environment and is just as exciting as buying a new one.